# Checking permissions on a directory - what does it mean?

Tags: unix

When checking the permissions on a directory I get:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096
```

I know what drwxrwxrwx is, but what are the other bits?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the break down of each info:

**d** - Directory

**rwx** - Owner permission

**rwx** - Group permission

**rwx** - Others permission

**2** - Num of link or directories inside this directory

**ubuntu** - Owner of the directory

**ubuntu** - Group directory belongs to

**4096** - size in bytes